# C# - How to close a form from a newly-opened form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form named frmDashboard and a frmBook.
When I click the add button from frmDashboard, frmBook will show up as a ShowDialog. How will I close the frmDashboard when I close frmBook?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: An insight into how your project is structured would help. Are you using an MDI form etc... please provide an exmaple of how you are launching your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
// Create a new instance of the form
frmBook bookform = new frm(Book);

// Hook a delegate to the Form_Closing event
bookform.Closing += delegate { this.Close(); }

// Show the new form
bookform.ShowDialog();
```